# "Host is down" after several hours

Tags: networking, mount, shared-folders

I have a shared USB HDD attached to my router that I have mounted as shown [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently).

After a few hours (around 12) I can no longer access the mounted drive with he error 'Host is down'. Restarting the computer allows me to access the drive again for another few hours.

The drive is in constant use as it contains video files which are slowly being transcoded on the computer. If the drive is used less frequently I do not get this problem.

Comment: If you can, try it with other disk. This looks to me like disk hardware problem.

Comment: @nobody The disk seems fine as I have no problem accessing the drive from other computers. My Ubuntu machine is the only one that fails.